# Python Selenium element.is_displayed returning true even when element is not visible on the page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am testing the functionality of a hamburger nav that displays a menu sidebar when clicked. The menu is hidden by setting `transform:TranslateX` to -17rem via css. Before clicking hamburger icon, the x property of the menu sidebar is -272 (not visible, not displayed). After clicking, the x property is 0 (you can see the menu on the page).

When I use the `element.is_displayed()` method before clicking, the method returns True even though the element is clearly, definitely not visible on the page.

I know that I can work around this, by checking the x coordinate, however, I am new to Python and Selenium and want to understand more about the is_displayed() method. Shouldn't this be returning False? What am I missing?

The only thing that I could think of is that when adding the x value plus the width, I can see that the width of the element starts at -272 and ends at 0 px (right edge of the element) before clicking. Is `is_displayed()` returning True because items ending at 0px are considered part of the viewport?

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4689

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("http://www.wesh.com")

#disable flex ad
driver.execute_script("""
        setInterval(function() {
            var $flex = document.querySelector("#ad-flex");
            //$flex.style.display = "none";
            $flex && $flex.parentNode && $flex.parentNode.removeChild($flex);
        }, 1);
        """)

#get menu sidebar, which is not visible initially unless you click the hamburger nav icon
sidebar = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("nav.sidepanel")
hamburger_nav = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.header-button.header-sidepanel-button")       

sidebar_visible_before = sidebar.is_displayed()
hamburger_nav.click()
time.sleep(.5)  
sidebar_visible_after = sidebar.is_displayed()

print("visible before click", sidebar_visible_before)
print("visible after click", sidebar_visible_after)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: This seems like a perennial problem with the `is_displayed` method. If you look at the [source](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.html#WebElement.is_displayed), it's documented as `"""Whether the element is visible to a user."""`, so if the element isn't visible to a user, I'd say this seems like a bug, but this method appears to be really unreliable.

Comment: Try using my library pyseleniumjs, https://github.com/neetVeritas/pyselenium-js.

In some scenarios an element may be hidden by overflow, which will not be caught using the official selenium api's methodology. I've written around this, just instantiate a new E2EJS object and call the method `is_visible`.